# Property (context) key doesn't work at all, in the Excel worksheet, on any cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, autohotkey

my property key doesn't work anymore in Excel: The key between right-ctrl and right-windows, that shows the context menu (the list of options for that cell, including "delete comment" etc).

My mouse right-click still works.

I use autohotkey where it could have been re-assigned with

```
appskey::  ;some code
```

But I did not do this assignment in Autohotkey. I also closed all the .ahk that were running and the issue still occurs. So it seems to have nothing to do with Autohotkey at all.

Some person said he could re-enable his mouse right-key with

```
Application.CommandBars("cell").Reset
Application.CommandBars("cell").Enabled = True
```

but this didn't work either. (My own right mouse-click has of course always still been working.)

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, here's what happened:

```
application.onkey "+{f10}", "One_Of_My_Macros"
```

The context key was then also re-assigned to this macro...
I removed this code and it worked.